# Horizontal scrollbar for a GridView, inside a Div, inside a Panel, inside a Div

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, scrollbar

Pretty convoluted, but I tried the old `overflow-x:auto` inside the Div above the GridView and it didn't work.  Anyone have any other solutions?  I'll try to keep the code to the relevant stuff, so my ASP looks *something* like this:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
   <div id="MainDiv" style="height:500px; margin-left:20px;">

      <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="ShowDiv1" Visible="false" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="0" Width="440px" Height="530px" style="margin-left:20px;">
         <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlStatusCode" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlStatusCode_OnSelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true">
            <asp:ListItem Value="1"> Open </asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="2"> Pended for Source Documents </asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="3"> Send to CSE </asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="4"> Send to Auditor </asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="5"> Assigned </asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="6"> Question to TC </asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>

        <!-- Leads: 1 -->
        <div id="divGrid_Open" runat="server" style='width:1350px; height:320px; overflow-x:auto'>
            <asp:GridView ID="DataGrid_Open" runat="server" 
                AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ShowFooter ="false" CellPadding="0" 
                CssClass="hoverTable"
                HeaderStyle-BackColor="#5D7B9D" HeaderStyle-BorderColor="#4DA6A6" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="White"
                HeaderStyle-Font-Size="x-Small" itemstyle-font-size="x-small" EditItemStyle-font-size="x-small"
                FooterStyle-BackColor="#5D7B9D" FooterStyle-BorderColor="#4DA6A6" FooterStyle-ForeColor="White"

                DataKeyNames="Audit_Number"
                OnRowCancelingEdit="DataGrid_Open_CancelCommand"
                OnRowDataBound="DataGrid_Open_RowDataBound" 
                OnDataBound="DataGrid_Open_OnDataBound"
                OnRowEditing="DataGrid_Open_EditCommand" 
                OnRowUpdating="DataGrid_Open_UpdateCommand">  
                <Columns>  
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Audit <br />Number" >  
                       <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center"></ItemStyle>
                       <ItemTemplate>  
                           <asp:Label ID="I_Open_AuditNbr" runat="server" Width="60px" Text='<%#Eval("Audit_Number") %>'></asp:Label>  
                       </ItemTemplate>  
                       <EditItemTemplate>  
                           <asp:Label ID="EI_Open_AuditNbr" runat="server" Width="60px" Text='<%#Eval("Audit_Number") %>'></asp:Label>  
                       </EditItemTemplate>  
                       <FooterTemplate>  
                           <asp:TextBox ID="F_Open_AuditNbr" runat="server" Width="60px" ></asp:TextBox>  
                       </FooterTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>                    

                        ETC....

                </Columns>  

            </asp:GridView>
            <asp:Label ID="lblEmpty1" runat="server" Visible="false" Style="font-weight:bold; font-size:large;"></asp:Label>
        </div>
    </asp:Panel>
  </div>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: Have you tried, emm, `overflow-x: scroll;`?

Comment: Also, what do you want to scroll, content of the inner div, the panel, or the outer div?

Comment: @Andrei - No joy with that.  :o(  I'd like to scroll the div that contains the Gridview.  Actually, I just want to scroll the GridView but I understand it needs to be inside of a div in order to do that.

Comment: Inspect the markup with something like Firebug or Chrome Dev Tools, I am pretty sure you have your overflow setting on a wrong tag. The inner div itself is wide, but the Panel and the outer div could be narrower, thus cutting the content. You may need to apply this setting to one of them instead

Comment: This ended up helping.  Turns out I need overflow on both divs.  Ugh...  Anyway, thanks for pushing me in the right direction.

Comment: Maybe post a self-answer in case anyone else finds this thread